# Executing Maven Project

Tags: maven

I wrote a test program to get familar with maven:

```
package com.mycompany.app;

import org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        List<String> someList = new ArrayList<String>();
        CollectionUtils.addAll(someList, new String[]{ "Hello ", "World"});
        System.out.println( someList.get(0)+someList.get(1) );
    }
}
```

And I added the commons-collections dependency to the pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I was able to compile it with

```
mvn clean package
```

How do I execute it?
I could find me the correct version of the commons-collection library and could run it by explicit mentioning it at the start, but at least the finding the correct version is job of maven.

If I want to give it to someone who doesn't has maven, what do I do?

I would expect there is a command that collects all dependent jars and put it in a folder.

Comment: If you want to offer someone else the code I would suggest to create a github repo which someone else clone. But that means to build it you have to use the defined tools that includes Maven in such case.. What I don't understand is: `but at least the finding the correct version is job of maven.` ? Can you clear that up?

Comment: Maven downloads the commons-collections.3.2.2.jar (or however it is called) somewhere into the .m2 folder.
That folder has a lot of jars and finding that one jar in that folder is work that maven can do better than me. 
Maven also knows the dependencies of commons-collections.3.2.2.jar and I don't. 
So maven can find the correct version of the jars and I don't.

Comment: Maven uses the version of jars you have defined in your project nothing else

Comment: And the jars that those jars need and the jars that those jars need and ...